# Kiel traduki «got him killed»?

Tags: translation

En la angla oni povas diri «got him killed» por paroli pri io kio kaŭzis ke io mortigis lin. Ekzemple:

> All that gambling got him killed in the end.

Do, tio estas ke la vetludado ne rekte mortigis lin, sed komencis sinsekvon de eventoj rezulte ke io alia mortigis lin.

Por aliaj similaj frazelturnoj, mi kredas ke oni simple aldonus *-ig-* al transitiva verbo. Ekzemple:

> I got my hair cut
>
> Mi tondigis mian hararon

Do, tio estas ke mi kaŭzis ke io tondis mian hararon, verŝajne hartondisto.

Tamen, la kutima maniero traduki *kill* estas *mortigi* kaj tio jam havas la finaĵon *-ig-*. Ĉu oni povas duobligi tiun finaĵon? Ekzemple:

> Lia vetludemo finfine mortigigis lin

Aŭ ĉu estas pli bona maniero esprimi tion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ebla elturniĝo por tio estas la jena vortumo:

> kosti al iu la vivon

Estas diversaj ekzemploj en [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/?s=5c77c14722adc) (serĉu ekz. `kost\VF .* vivon`). Jen iu, kiu kongruas kun via celata signifo:

> Tiu fanfaronado kostis al li la vivon.

—Fabeloj de Andersen 4

Answer (score 3):

Mi dirus:

Lia vetludemo finfine mortigis lin

(nur trois "ig" en via frazo)

Aliaj alternativoj estas:

"kostis al li la vivon", aŭ eble io kiel "vetludemo destinis morton por li"

Comment: Mi ŝatus emfazi per la frazo ke ne estis rekte la vetludemo kiu mortigis lin, sed tio nur kaŭzis ke io alia mortigis lin. Mi pensas ke tiu signifo perdiĝus se oni tradukas ĝin simple per «mortigis lin».

Comment: Prave ... do, la respondo "kostis al li la vivon" bonas, aŭ eble io kiel "vetludemo destinis morton por li"

Answer (score 0):

La sufikso **-ig-** signifas, ke io kaûzis tio kio staras antaû **-ig-**.

Ĉar **morti** estas *to die*, **mortigi** signifas *to kill*.

> Lia vetludemo finfine mortigigis lin.

signifus, ke lia vetludemo kaûzis, ke li mortigis.

> All that gambling got him killed in the end.

estas *causative passive* kaj estas direbla

> ... got him being killed ...

*Being killed* estas pasivo kaj ĉar li jam estas morta oni uzus participo pasiva perfekto: *Li mortigitis.*

Nun ni povas uzi la sufikson *-ig-* por diri, ke lia vetludemo kaûzis, ke li mortigitis.

**Lia vetludemo finfine mortigitigis lin.**

**Kialo:**

La sufikso **-ig* ne faris aktivan agon passiva* kvankam angla traduko uzanti *causative passive* sugestius ĝin.

> Oni ofte demandadis sin, ĉu kun la verbaj radikoj *igi* signifas *igi -anta* aŭ *igi -ata*. Sed la demando per si mem estas ne ĝusta, ĉar *igi* kun verbo signifas nek *igi -anta*, nek *igi -ata*, sed nur *igi -i*.
>
> -- Zamenhof, Lingva Respondo 13. (La Revuo, 1907, Aprilo)

La frazo

> Mi tondigis mian hararon.

signifas: *Mi igis iun tondi mian hararon.* Ne gravas kiu tondis ĝin, sed la haroj ne povas tondi. Frazo estas klara.

En la frazo

> Ŝi manĝigis avenon al la ĉevalo.

ŝi igis la ĉevalon manĝi avenon. Manĝigi signifas *to make someone eat something*. Aveno ne povas manĝi. Frazo estas klara. (Kvankam mi dirus *Ŝi paŝtis avenon al la ĉevalo.* aû *Ŝi paŝtis la ĉevalon kun aveno.*)

> ... se mi, sen plua precizigo per *al*, diros mi manĝigas mian ĉevalon, neniu dubos pri la senco de la frazo); fine en tiuj tre maloftaj okazoj, kiam ni efektive povas timi malkompreniĝon, ni ja tute ne bezonas aktivigi aŭ pasivigi la sencon de la sufikso *ig*, sed ni povas tute bone kaj regule aktivigi aŭ pasivigi la verbon, dirante manĝantigi, kaj manĝatigi. La sufikso *ig* per si mem ne havas kaj ne devas havi ian sencon aldonan, kiun ĝi per si mem ne havas kaj ne devas havi kaj kiu (en okazo de efektiva neceseco) devas esti esprimata per alia rimedo ...
>
> -- Zamenhof ib.

Se vi fikcius, ke *-ig* povus ŝanĝi aktivon en la pasivo, tiam en la frazo

> Lia vetludemo finfine mortigigis lin.

ne estus klara, ĉu la vetludemo faris lin mortigi aû ĉu iu/io mortigis lin. Imageblus ke li mortigis iun kaj ankaû imageblus ke iu/io mortigis lin. Mi supozas la ĉirkaûteksto klarigus ĝin. Sed sensencas precizi la diferenco, ĉu la vetludemo mortigis lin rekte aû ne kaj malprecizas ĉu li mortis âu mortigis.

Comment: La sufikso -ig- povas signifi ankaŭ la pasivan kaŭzon. Ekzemple en la frazo “mi tondigis mian hararon”, la hararo ne tondas ion. Estas ekzemploj de tio en PMEG: “Ŝi manĝigis avenon al la ĉevalo” (ne la aveno manĝas sed la ĉevalo) https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ig.html#i-g6g

Comment: Jen bona remarko. Bonvolu ekzameni mian prilaboritan respondon.

Comment: La aldonita komento estas bona, sed ĝi ne tre kongruas kun la cetero de la respondo kiu ankoraŭ havas «signifus, ke lia vetludemo kaûzis, ke li mortigis». Tio estas iom misgvida ĉar la dua ebla signifo estas nur en la dua parto de la respondo. Mi pensas ke estus bone konservi nur la duan parton.

Comment: Multan dankon por la rimarko. Mi forgesis diri, ke la lasta paragrafo hipotezis. Mi prilaboris mian respondon denove. Ankaû dankon por la interesa demando. Mi ĝuis okupiĝi pri ĝi.